# Performance Impact of DescribeSObjects vs. Individual Describe Calls?

Tags: apex, bestpractice, performance, describes

I've been wondering this for a while, so it's time to put this question out there. How does `Schema.describeSObjects` perform when compared to individual calls to `SObjectType.getDescribe`?

For example, which of these is faster? By how much?

```
static Map<String, SObjectType> globalDescribe = Schema.getGlobalDescribe();
public static List<DescribeSObjectResult> getIndividualDescribes(List<String> types)
{
    List<DescribeSObjectResult> describes = new List<DescribeSObjectResult>();
    for (String sObjectType : types)
        describes.add(globalDescribe.get(sObjectType).getDescribe());
    return describes;
}
public static List<DescribeSObjectResult> getBulkDescribes(List<String> types)
{
    return Schema.describeSObjects(types);
}
```

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Getting the individual describes is *significantly faster*. Depending on your situation, it is anywhere from 14 to 850 times as fast!

**Describing Many Objects Once**

The first continuum I profiled is the situation where you have many objects to describe and make one call to describe all of them.

The individual `getDescribe` approach can describe anywhere from 5 to 11 objects per millisecond, whereas the bulk `describeSObjects` approach takes anywhere from 2 to 3.5 milliseconds per object. In this continuum, individual describes perform roughly 14 to 30 times better than the bulk describe method.

Here is the amount of CPU time consumed for each approach to describe a given number of sObjects once:

```
Objects  |  Individual  |    Bulk  |  Multiplier
================================================
      5  |         1.1  |    17.5  |        15.9
     10  |         1.5  |    24.6  |        16.4
     15  |         2.1  |    29.7  |        14.1
     20  |         2.6  |    38.7  |        14.9
     25  |         2.8  |    71.4  |        25.5
     30  |         3.1  |    88.7  |        28.6
     35  |         3.3  |   107.7  |        32.6
     40  |         4.6  |   117.2  |        25.5
     45  |         4.3  |   133.4  |        31.0
     50  |         4.7  |   144.3  |        30.7
     55  |         5.2  |   151.4  |        29.1
     60  |         5.9  |   153.7  |        26.1
     65  |         6.2  |   156.5  |        25.2
     70  |         6.8  |   167.3  |        24.6
     75  |         7.3  |   174.7  |        23.9
     80  |         7.6  |   184.7  |        24.3
     85  |         7.9  |   192.4  |        24.4
     90  |         9.0  |   193.0  |        21.4
     95  |         8.7  |   198.1  |        22.8
    100  |         9.1  |   209.7  |        23.0
```

**Describing One Object Many Times**

The second continuum I profiled is the situation where you describe one object many times, for instance if you have describes in a loop somewhere in your code.

The individual `getDescribe` approach can describe an object anywhere from 17 to 33 times per second, whereas the bulk `describeSObjects` approach takes anywhere from 25 to 29 milliseconds per describe. In this continuum, individual describes perform hundreds of times better than the bulk describe method.

Here is the amount of CPU time consumed for each approach to describe one object (`User`) a given number of times:

```
Iterations  |  Individual  |     Bulk  |  Multiplier
====================================================
        25  |         1.5  |    719.7  |       479.8
        50  |         2.6  |   1408.4  |       541.7
        75  |         2.9  |   2147.9  |       740.7
       100  |         4.3  |   2782.4  |       647.1
       125  |         4.4  |   3667.9  |       833.6
       150  |         5.2  |   4171.3  |       802.2
       175  |         6.1  |   4640.4  |       760.7
       200  |         7.3  |   5167.1  |       707.8
       225  |         7.2  |   5887.2  |       817.7
       250  |         7.8  |   6618.9  |       848.6
       275  |         8.7  |   7175.3  |       824.7
       300  |         9.0  |   7537.6  |       837.5
       325  |         9.8  |   8328.8  |       849.9
       350  |        11.1  |   9090.1  |       818.9
       375  |        12.9  |   9423.5  |       730.5
       400  |        12.3  |  10422.8  |       847.4
       425  |        13.5  |  10716.1  |       793.8
       450  |        13.6  |  11431.6  |       840.6
       475  |        14.5  |  12063.8  |       832.0
       500  |        14.8  |  12977.7  |       876.9
```

Comment: I know it won't be dynamic, but what if you compare Schema.getGlobalDescribe().get('Account') with Account.sObjectType.getDescribe() or Schema.SObjectType.Account? What do you think would be faster ?

Comment: Sounds like a separate question! One which I would also be happy to profile if no one beats me to it. Note that if you are calling `Schema.getGlobalDescribe` many times that will affect performance, and the first iteration is slower than the rest. I think `SObjectType.Account` is fastest, but I've never checked.

Comment: @AdrianLarson - Sorry, confused describesObjects with the global call

Answer (score 2):

I re-ran the this scenario and looks like Schema.describeSObjects seems to have better performance now when compared to SObjectType.getDescribe for individual objects, I'm assuming salesforce must have optimised this flow.

Below is the profiler trace for 'Account' and 'Product2' objects.

[image]